# CoordinatorLayout Is is pushed out of the screen for no reason

Tags: android, xml, layout

[image]

this layout has a collapsible action bar then a tabs bar and then the list of cards. when you scroll down to see all the cards the action bar will collapse and the tabs bar will stay there at the top.

I want the collapsible action bar first then the tabs bar then the list of card, I tried to put them in a liner layout but it did not work.

here is my layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:expanded="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="4dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cardiff_logo"
                        android:layout_width="216dp"
                        android:layout_height="101dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        />

                    <customfonts.MyTextView
                        android:id="@+id/app_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Explore The University"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_title" />

                    <customfonts.MyTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="From Inside"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/backdrop_subtitle" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Does it affect on your layout when you run the app?

Comment: yes, only the cardView is there, everything else is out of the screen